# Regex string parsing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this set (number of points variable, here 2):

```
A 
 This is some Text belonging to A
 This also belongs to A
B 
 This should be with B
 same with this
...
...
```

I want it to finally be a string like that:

```
A This is some Text belonging to A This also belongs to A
B This should be with B same with this
```

My try was something like:

```
answer.scan(/^([A-Z].+?(?=^[A-Z]))/m).map { |d| d.delete("\n") }.join("\n")
```

The problem is that this doesn't match the last set (you can assume the string ends with the last set)
any ideas? :)

edit1: fixed a coyping error & tried a new regex in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/7kAKDR9uRb) which kind of works but still has some unnecessary matches?

Comment: I'll suggest http://www.rubular.com - a regexp tester for Ruby!

Comment: Maybe regex isn't the solution to your problem

Comment: @ nikola. most questions didnt really get "good" or productive answers except maybe the Backbone one, which I abandoned since I stopped that project. Therefore I can't really say if its correct or not. (And the Question concerning tabs probably didn't belong here anyhow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
answer = answer
.scan(/^([A-Z].+?(?=^[A-Z]))|(^[A-Z].+?\Z)/m)
.map {|item| item.reject { |i| i.nil? } }
.map { |d| d[0].delete("\n") }
.join("\n")
```

seems to work for now... probably not the best possible way though

Answer (score 4):

```
text = <<EOS
A 
 This is some Text belonging to A
 This also belongs to A
B 
 This should be with B
 same with this
 variable line
EOS

text.gsub(/\s?\n\s/, ' ')

# Outputs: 
# A This is some Text belonging to A This also belongs to A
# B This should be with B same with this variable line
```

Comment: think that would only work for 2 sets? with 3 it doesnt seem to insert a newline between 2 and 3

Comment: with set I mean an upper case letter and then some text. have managed to do it now, although it seems a bit messy...